# DICOM file with CT and MR tags

Tags: image-processing, dicom, medical, tomography-reconstruction

A DICOM file (an artificial axial slice) has been generated from both a CT and an MR images. Can the aggregated file contain both CT and MR DICOM tags? E.g. `Echo Time (0x18, 0x81)` and `KVP (0x18,0x60)`?

I cannot find any information whether one image modality module is exclusive of the other and want to find out if such an artificial image might run into troubles with other vendors' software. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute SOP Class UID (0008,0016) determines which "type of object" you have and by this, the so-called Information Object Definition (IOD). The IOD tells you, which attributes are mandatory and which are allowed (and implicitly: which are not allowed) for the type of object.

So, merging attributes about the acquisition processes from two different IODs is not a good idea. What is going to fail widely is the annotation of these objects in a DICOM viewer. Most viewers have a SOP Class- or Modality- dependent configuration that defines how the images are annotated with DICOM header information. SOP Class UID and Modality have to provide exactly one value which cannot be entirely right in your case. So you have to decide whether another application treats the images as "CT only" or "MR only".

So, there is no way of merging IOD tables and still claiming DICOM conformance for the application that generates images of this type.

A lot of systems I know just treat the DICOM header as a "stream of attributes" not looking at correctness and consistency. As long as your pixel data and ordering information (Patient name, ID, ... , Study Instance UID, Series Instance UID) is properly encoded, it might happen that you will not run into severes issues.

However, I would never advise anyone to implement such thing. It is just a question of time when someone will validate your objects against the DICOM standard, find out that they are blatantly wrong and blaming no one else than you for that.

Comment: Basically, I agree with your answer... apart from your statement "So, there is no way of merging IOD tables and still claiming DICOM conformance for the application that generates images of this type." This is because, under certain conditions, it is actually possible. This type of SOP Class is called "Standard Extended SOP Class": http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/html/part02.html#sect_3.11.3 -- And, of course, there are also Specialized and Private SOP Classes :-)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, this is really new to me. Have you ever seen Standard Extended SOP Classes in practice?

Comment: @J.Riesmeier one important point you neglected is [7.3 Rules Governing Types of SOP Classes](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part02/sect_7.3.html): "not change the semantics of any Standard Attribute of that Standard SOP Class". So please tell me what does "kVp" means for an MR instance ? The answer to OP is clearly: no, no doubt about it.

Comment: @ kritzel_sw Yes, I have seen Standard Extended SOP Classes in the wild but not mixing CT and MR, which probably does not really make sense (as @malat pointed out with an example). However, sometimes the Secondary Capture Image IOD is extended by some Standard Attributes. Anyway, with my original comment I just wanted to point out that the sentence from @ kritzel_sw I was referring to is not 100% correct.

Comment: How can we distinguish CT and MRT using SOP Class UID (0008,0016)? What are the possible values? The DICOM documents are not really helpful...

Comment: @Trantor: Agreed they are not *always* really helpful ;-) However in this case they are: http://dicom.nema.org/Dicom/2013/output/chtml/part04/sect_B.5.html

Answer (score 2):

As explained by other, you are required to follow the DICOM standard. Basically you need to implement what is defined in the related IOD of your SOP Class instance.

Again as explained by other you are allowed to use a so-called 'Standard Extended SOP Class'. But be sure to read the definition for such class:

- [7.3 Rules Governing Types of SOP Classes](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part02/sect_7.3.html)

Quoting the paragraph:

> Standard Extended SOP Classes shall:
>
> 1. be a proper super set of one Standard SOP Class;
> 2. not change the semantics of any Standard Attribute of that Standard SOP Class;
> 3. not contain any Private Type 1, 1C, 2, or 2C Attributes, nor add additional Standard Type 1, 1C, 2 or 2C Attributes;
> 4. not change any Standard Type 3 Attributes to Type 1, 1C, 2, or 2C;
> 5. use the same UID as the Standard SOP Class on which it is based.

So in summary no, you certainly cannot create an MR instance with a left over kVp (0018,0060) attribute, it cannot possibly mean anything for a MR modality in which case you are changing the semantics of a public attribute.

Comment: thanks a lot for the info! A not of clarification: my extended class would be based on the CT SOP class and will not change the semantic of the CT SOP class. It will introduce additional type 3 attributes like the Echo Time tag. Do you see any problem with such a setup?